# Bouncy Castle JCA Provider Version In Classpath Ignored by Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, cryptography, bouncycastle, jca

I am getting a wrong keystore version error on my spring boot application when I attempt to instantiate my keystore that relies on bouncy castle 1.46. 
I added the right version 1.46 on pom.xml and even on my classpath but when I execute the spring-boot application, a version check on the Bouncy Castle provider at runtime indicates version 1.51.

How do I ensure the spring-boot application runs Bouncy Castle 1.46 defined on my pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.46</version>
</dependency>
```

---

```
private void installJCAProvider() {
    BouncyCastleProvider bouncyCastleProvider = new BouncyCastleProvider();

    System.err.println("Bouncy Catle Provider Version " + bouncyCastleProvider.getVersion() + " \nName " + bouncyCastleProvider.getName() + " | \n" + bouncyCastleProvider.getInfo());


    Security.addProvider(bouncyCastleProvider);

    Provider[] providers = Security.getProviders();

    for (Provider provider : providers) {
        System.err.println("Installed security providers" + 

        provider.getInfo() + "\n");
    }
}
```

---

Logs

```
Bouncy Castle Provider Version 1.51 
Name SC | 
BouncyCastle Security Provider v1.51
```

Comment: You check all your dependencies, since one of them apparently depends on version 1.51. Try a *web search* for [`maven show dependencies`](https://www.google.com/search?q=maven+show+dependencies). Once you find the cause, use more *web searches* to find out how to solve it.

Comment: More web searches! Funny, this always happens to me when I have to work with Bouncy Castle.  Let me check my dependencies...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `mvn dependency:tree` to see where version `1.51` came from and exclude it from dependencies.

Also spring-boot has a set of properties declared in its `POMs` defining versions of dependencies. So look up into a POM of a spring-boot starter using Bouncy Castle lib for the property defining version and redefine its value in your POM.

According to this https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html
You can try to trick Maven with placing your dependency declaration above of the spring-boot starter in dependencies list.

Answer (score 0):

@Danila 's answer helped a lot, however,  also follow the instructions provided by oracle to add bouncy castle version 1.46 {or your prefered version} to the list of CSPs - Cryptography Service Providers in your $JAVA_HOME https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19830-01/819-4712/ablsc/index.html cheers!